# Best practice for attaching handlers (with different actions) to multiple generated elements?

Tags: javascript

Say I'm dynamically generating some controls (example using jQuery):

```
for (var c=0 ; c<100 ; c++) {
  $(body).append('<input id="btn_'+c+'" type="button" value="Button #'+c+'" />');
}
```

And I want them to have different action depending on which one is clicked (mouseover, etc), what is the best practice for attaching a handler so it knows which button is being clicked? I can think of 3 alternatives:

1. Attach the same handler (via javascript) to all buttons and have the handler parse the element id to determine which one is clicked
2. Add the handlers inline when generating the HTML for the controls (ie have onclick="do_something('+c+');")
3. Attach different handler (eg with a loop) for each element that has the button number set in the handler argument

Which method is preferred or is there another alternative?

**Edit:**

Sorry, but I should probably mention that the number of generated elements are variable and the handler only needs the button number (ie not a completely different handler function for each button). A simple example use case would be a list grabbed via ajax that you want the user to order, in this case the handler would just need the index number for the list.

For fixed number of elements with distinct handlers David's answer makes sense.

Comment: between 1 and 2 there is finally no difference. choose one of them. the last one is bad because you wouldn't reuse existing code even if you not have to write it down all the time. 1 or 2 are the most common approaches.

Comment: Regarding method 3, if you attach a handler to every button you don't need to set the button number as an argument because you can use `this` within the function.

Comment: 4. Delegate the handler to a higher up element and filter the elements in the event handler for that higher up element, so you'll only need one event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I would say [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) is preferred in this case:

```
$('body').on('click', 'input', function(e) {
    // do something with this (the element that was clicked)
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

This way only one event listener is attached to the button’s parent (the `body` in this example), but you can still access the button element that was clicked in the handler.

You can f.ex map actions to the buttons like this:

```
for (var c=0 ; c<100 ; c++) {
    $('body').append('<input id="btn_'+c+'" type="button" value="Button #'+c+'" />');
}

var actions = {
    btn_0: function() {
        console.log('btn 0 clicked');
    },
    btn_1: function() {
        console.log('btn 1 clicked');
    }
    // etc...
};

$('body').on('click', 'input', function(e) {
    $.isFunction(actions[this.id]) && actions[this.id].call(this);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was actually trying to handle a variable number of generated elements with a handler that operates on the button number, which I should've specified on the question. Still, I didn't know about event delegation before and it was good info to know. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 is most flexible.
"event delegation" mentioned by David is also just a variation of your method 1 (if you turn the Object key into a function param). When used together with other event assignment, you can flexibly turn on / off different handling over the same object. You can also handle "event propagation" better.

Method 2 is simple but it has limited capability and is a bit odd when used together with other methods to register event handler such as jQuery. A nice article to read about inline handler: https://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/working-with-inline-event-handlers.html

Method 3 sounds bad in performance as the function has to be complied many times, and will make your code harder to maintain.